# Perform replace operation on selected (highlighted) string

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

In visual code, let say I have a string:

`I need this feature urgently!`

When I **select** the text "urgently" and **press** `Cntrl + 1`, then visual code will **change** the *selected string* as such:

`I need this feature <span class="warn">urgently</span>!`

Is it possible in visual code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that easily with a snippet.  Put this into your keybindings.json:

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+k ctrl+1",
    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
      "args": {
        "snippet": "<span class=\"warn\">$TM_SELECTED_TEXT</span>",
    }
},
```

I used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> as the keybinding because <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> already is bound to the focus first editor group command, but you may or may not care keeping that functionality.

If you really want to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> as your snippet's keybinding, put this into your keybindings.json:

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+1",
    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
      "args": {
        "snippet": "<span class=\"warn\">$TM_SELECTED_TEXT</span>",
    }
},
{
  "key": "ctrl+1",
  "command": "-workbench.action.focusFirstEditorGroup"
},
```

The `-` before `-workbench.action.focusFirstEditorGroup` removes that keybinding.